# Changing textbox value by +/-10

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

Today I've started a project and added Theme to project. But this theme doesn't have **DomainUpDown** component, so I decided to do it myself.

I've added a textbox and two buttons (up and down).

- When I click **Up**, I need value of textbox += 10 (textbox value increased by 10)
- When I click **Down**, textbox -= 10 (textbox value reduced by 10)

I've tried this, but I get an error:

```
 txtThreads.Text += 10;
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is this a web forms project, or Windows Forms?

Answer (score 5):

You need to convert the text box text to a number, then increment, then set back:

```
int value;
int.TryParse(txtThreads.Text, out value); // Ignoring return - bad text becomes 0, which in turn becomes 10 after increment
value += 10;
txtThreads.Text = value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
txtThreads.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtThreads.Text) + 10).ToString();
```

Comment: This will work, but raise an exception if the text box is blank, etc

Comment: Assigning an integer to string?

Comment: @NikolaMalešević: No Assigning a string to textbox.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal After your edit, you're assigning a string to string, not a textbox.

Comment: @NikolaMalešević: Read carefully.

Comment: `Text` is a property of `TextBox` class and it has a type of `string`. `ToString()` method has a return value of `string`. You are assigning a `string` value to a variable of type `string`. Am I missing something? We are getting a bit off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a way to count up and down from a value given from a textbox. To accomplish this, you'll need to convert the string to an integer or other numeric value type.

Try this:

```
private void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbVal.Text = (int.Parse(tbVal.Text) + 10).ToString();
}

private void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbVal.Text = (int.Parse(tbVal.Text) - 10).ToString();
}
```

Hope this helps!